# How to turn on location in maui?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have to turn on location or navigate to location settings.I have tried to use code like in xamarin app:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
```

But it doesn't work.

How to do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=ios

Answer (score 1):

To navigate to location settings you can use this code for android

```
#if ANDROID
using Android.Content;

#if ANDROID
    var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
    intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
#endif
```